# how to implement the function like left join of mysql in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am going to implement the function like left join of mysql in mongoose.
the date is

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' },
  title    : String
});

var personProfile = Schema({
   userid : {type: Number, ref: 'Person'},
   birthday: Date,
   profilelink: String,
   email: String
});

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
var personProfile = mongoose.model('Personprofile', personProfile );
```

I am going to display the Story model with the user profile.
We have to get the profile info with the _creator of story and the userid of  personProfile

How can I get the info using mongoose query?

Thanks Nelis

Comment: Do you mean following the refs via Mongoose [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) or something else?  Could you edit your question to include the query you're using and the desired output?

Answer (score 3):

What your are trying to do is not possible because there is no join statement on mongodb.

You can achieve this in two ways:

1 - **By DBRefs:** Changing your Schema to one that include all the user info and do not split them in two different schemas as you are doing, see [denormalized](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/). Then you can use the [Population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) function to get all the persons data.

2 - **By Manual references:** The second solution is to make a second call to the database getting the personProfile data using the userid as a filter.

Example 1:

This way you can get all persons data without a second call to the database.

```
var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  birthday: Date,
  profilelink: String,
  email: String
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator : { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  title    : String
});

Story
.find()
.populate(['_creator'])
.exec(function(err, stories) {
    //do your stuff here
}
```

Notice that I'm using the type **Schema.Types.ObjectId** and not the **Number**. This way, you can assign a new value to **_creator** passing either the **_id** or the **person object** and the mongoose will convert the object to its _id. For example, you can post something like

```
{
    _creator : {
        _id     : 123123123123,
        name    : 'Foo',
        birthday: '0000-00-00',
        profilelink: 'http://foo.bar',
        email: 'foo@bar.com'
    },
    title    : 'Mr'
}
```

... and the mongoose will convert to

```
{
    _creator : 123123123123,
    title    : 'Mr'
}
```

Example 2:

This way your data still normalized and you can get all the persons data with a second call.

```
Story
.find()
.exec(function(err, stories) {
    var arrayLength = stories.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        var story = stories[i];
        personProfile.findById(story._creator, function (err, person) {
            story._creator = person;
        }
    };
    // do your stuff here
}
```