# How to do `where foo_id in (select id from foo)` in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, where-in

I have two collections in my MongoDB with the following structure:

```
// user
{
    _id: <ObjectId>,
    name: <string>
}

// article
{
    _id: <ObjectId>,
    userId: <ObjectId>,
    title: <string> 
}
```

I need to get all articles of all users with name Alex. If I had a relational database, I'd write the following SQL query:

```
select * from article
where userId in (select _id from user where name = 'Alex')
```

How do I do the same but with MongoDB?

BTW, I'm using Node.js and Mongoose

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948298/how-to-implement-the-function-like-left-join-of-mysql-in-mongoose) answers your question?

Comment: @ISAE no, it doesn't. I don't need to join data, I need some alternative to subqueries in the where clause

Comment: Tthe principal is the same, mongoDb in NOT a relational database, so you'll have to do two separate queries